# Make display table-cell use percentage width

Tags: html, css

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qy7ad/)

I've got this table feel going, using an unordered list. But I can't figure out how to get the table-cells to have 50% width (I want each row to be 100% width). The reason I am using `display: table-row;` and `display: table-cell;` is so that I can vertical-align the data if the parameter text is more than one line. I don't want to use an actual pixel or em value for the width, because, well, I just want it in percentage if its possible. I would rather give up the vertical-align. Please no javascript. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div class="group group2">
    <h2>Health Indicies</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><p class="parameter">GGP</p><p class="data">265</p></li>
        <li><p class="parameter">Comfort</p><p class="data">blah</p></li>
        <li><p class="parameter">Energy</p><p class="data">gooo</p></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.group {
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px gray;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.group h2 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: gray;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
.group li {
    clear: both;
}
.group p {
    padding: 3%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.group2 li {
    display: table-row;
}
.group2 p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 46%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
}
.group li:last-child p {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't use `display: table-cell` without a parent element using `display: table-row`, and `table-row` in turn needs to live in a `display: table` context.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You're almost there. You just need to add `display: table` and `width: 100%` to your `ul.group2`. You could probably also get away with not supplying a `width` on your `.group2 p` elements.

This should work: http://jsfiddle.net/6Kn88/2/

```css
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.group {
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px gray;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.group h2 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: gray;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
.group li {
    clear: both;
}
.group p {
    padding: 3%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.group2 ul {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.group2 li {
    display: table-row;
}
.group2 p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 46%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
}
.group li:last-child p {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="group group2">
    <h2>Health Indicies</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><p class="parameter">GGP</p><p class="data">265</p></li>
        <li><p class="parameter">Comfort</p><p class="data">blah</p></li>
        <li><p class="parameter">Energy</p><p class="data">gooo</p></li>
    </ul>
    <span class="clear"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Set the `ul` to `display: table` in accordance with the rest of your CSS, and give it a width of 100% to fill the parent div. Now your widths should take hold for your "rows" and "cells".

Edit: As per kpeatt, above, who was quicker off the mark!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
  display:table-cell;
  width: 100vw;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way to set table-cell div 100% width from bootstrap source code.

Set `width:10000px`, it rendered like 100% width.

> https://jsfiddle.net/y3qsxb9m/

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Answers are supposed to be explanatory, so please add some explanations why it solves the problem the questioner is stating.

Answer (score -8):

For

```
display: table-cell;
```

setting

```
width:10000px;
```

acted as

```
width:100%;
```

So, If you want 50% of width just use

```
width: 5000px;
```

Comment: That*s a very poor advise.